# Select en laravel no funciona con clave foranea (Laravel 10)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Buenas estoy queriendo hacer una simple query

`$productos = Producto::where('categoria_id', '=', 2)->get();`

El campo categoria_id es un foreing key a la tabla "categorias" y guarda un big int. 1, 2, 3 y 4.

No se porque motivo no me trae nada, cuando si existen productos que tengan categoria_id en 2. Busque por todos lados pero no encuentro si hay otra forma de hacerlo, es en laravel 10.

Como se que existen productos con categoria_id ?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco cualquier ayuda.

Comment: La query es correcta. A que te refieres con **"no me trae nada"**? Como estas debugando el resultado? Y en que te basas para afirmar que **"existen productos que tengan categoria_id en 2"**?

Comment: Ahí te edite la publi, si le pongo algun otro campo me trae resultados, y lo debuggeo retornando la respuesta de la query, por ejemplo return $productos;

Comment: La verdad que no veo nada raro ahí. Te diría que pruebes sin el `'='` por las dudas `Producto::where('categoria_id', 2)->get();` aunque así como ya lo tienes debería funcionar. O ya que tienes phpmyadmin, probar directamente la sentencia SQL ahí, para ver si ahí sí te devuelve las filas `SELECT * FROM productos WHERE categoria_id = 2;`